# How to change dialog box message based on window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, xaml

I am trying to find a way to display a different message in my dialog box depending on which window user is in.

**Example**

If user is in MainWindow.xaml and clicks the close button the message in the dialog box should say "Are you sure you wish to close MainWindow?"

If user is on MainWindowTwo.xaml then "Are you sure you wish to close MainWindowTwo?"

This is my current code which appears when user clicks the close button.

**XAML**

```
<Border BorderBrush="#081e2b" BorderThickness="2">

    <Grid Background="#fff">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="110" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <DockPanel Width="400" Background="#081e2b">

            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#f12c00">
                <Button x:Name="CloseWindow" Content="X" Click="CloseWindow_Click" Height="40"></Button>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Content="Are you sure you wish to logout?" FontSize="16"></Label>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#FFE6E6E6" >
                <Button Click="YesClose_Click" x:Name="YesClose" FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="Yes" Height="50" Background="#FFE6E6E6" Foreground="#081e2b" BorderBrush="#FFE6E6E6" Width="200"></Button>
                <Button Click="NoClose_Click" x:Name="NoClose" FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="No" Height="50" Background="#FFE6E6E6" Foreground="#081e2b" BorderBrush="#FFE6E6E6" Width="200"></Button>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**C#**

```
private void YesClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var closeapp = Application.Current.Windows[0];
        closeapp.Close();

        Login.LoginScreen logscreen = new Login.LoginScreen();
        logscreen.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void NoClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void CloseWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Really would appreciate any help with this as I am pretty new to WPF, I have been playing around with this for a few days now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, I would
create variable with text and for example bind it to your label:

```
<Label Content="{Binding QuestionText}" ...
```

This variable I would set in constructor

```
LoginScreen(string message)
{
    this.QuestionText = message;
}
```

and depend on MainWindow or MainWindowTwo contruct LoginScreen with desired text.

It can be handled in different ways, maybe I didn't think of the optimum, but it should work